# sort values using calculation in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i wanted to sort the length of the message of the column without adding new column in dataframes.tried the below method and didnt work ..is there any way to sort values based on the any custom function.

```
df.sort_values(df['message'].apply(len),ascending=False)
```

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `len()` of the string (message) as the `key` parameter in `sort_values()`.

Consider a random `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'messages':['come here please as I need you','why would i come there','fine i will be there soon']})

df

                         messages
0  come here please as I need you
1          why would i come there
2       fine i will be there soon
```

Use:

```
df.sort_values(by='messages', key=lambda x: x.str.len(),ascending=False,inplace=True)
```

---

```
df

                         messages
0  come here please as I need you
2       file i will be there soon
1          why would i come there
```

So you were almost there.

For more information on the parameters on `sort_values` check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=['ab','effg','hjj','klllh','m','n','abbc']


df=pd.DataFrame(data={'message':l1})

df['message']=list(df['message'][df['messsage'].apply(lambda x:len(x)).sort_values(ascending=False).index])

print(df)
```

get the  sorted index and apply this index on messages

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyxzL.png